# is there any wordpress plugin to show demographic of certain fields into my website

Tags: wordpress, elementor

i want to show certain demographics in my website currently its not what i want

https://wess.org.pk/sustainable-livelihood/

it looks very stuffed , is any other way to show this data in presentable way and not stuffed ? i tried different method but not useful result. you can take a look at this part also

https://wess.org.pk/community-development-and-empowerment/

this website is mainly for demographics but currently its not the way we want it to be

i am asking for different method in place of counter to show my demographics in . should be more readable

currently my site uses counter but i don't want to use counter for demographics

Answer (score 0):

You easily do that with CSS.
But should in case you don't know the HTML ID or class of the demographics, just try and use a browser vide inspector to find out it's class or id which you can use to style it on your CSS file.

Comment: currently my site uses counter but i don't want to use counter for demographics.